# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

from google.colab import files
upload=files.upload()

acci = pd.read_csv('acci.csv')
acci
```

---

**Error**

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-79ae4a7ed032> in <module>()
----> 1 acci = pd.read_csv('acci.csv')
      2 acci

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1996         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1997 
-> 1998         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1999         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   2000 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the file with UTF-8 and Import with encoding UTF-8:

```
acci = pd.read_csv('acci.csv',encoding='utf-8')
```

Or try:

```
acci = pd.read_csv('acci.csv',engine='python')
```

Comment: They're both not working.